# (Python 3.6) TypeError: can't concat bytes to tuple

Tags: python, mysql, concatenation

I am trying to insert scraped items ('title') into a mySQL database.

This is the snippet of my spider.py file that scrapes 'title' content:

```
#get more details
def parse_detail_page(self, response):
    item = response.meta["item"]

    #title
    title = response.xpath(".//*[@id='titletextonly']/text()").extract()[0]
    item["title"] = title

    return item
```

This is my pipelines.py file:

```
import pymysql.cursors

class mySQLTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='testDB',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                          cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()


    def process_item (self, item, spider):
        sql = "INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s)", (item['title'])
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        self.conn.commit()

        return item
```

I am running into the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/venv1/tutorial/tutorial/pipelines.py", line 31, in process_item
    self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/Users/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/Users/sandysu/PyCharmProjects/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 322, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/Users/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 855, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/Users/venv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1091, in _execute_command
    packet = prelude + sql[:packet_size-1]
TypeError: can't concat bytes to tuple
```

What does this **TypeError: can't concat bytes to tuple** mean?  How should it be fixed?

Comment: What if you use: `sql = "INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES ("+item['title']+")"` instead?

Comment: How about `sql = "INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES ({0})".format(item['title'])`

Comment: @user3450049 - can you clarify what the purpose is of {0}?  I tried what you suggested and got this error: pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'prime location - s/s appliances- h/w floors - Avail:  July 1st' at line 1")

For reference, the 'title' scraped reads as follows: 'AAA prime location - s/s appliances- h/w floors - Avail:  July 1st'.

Comment: @nikpod - I tried what you suggested and got this error: pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'prime location - s/s appliances- h/w floors - Avail: July 1st' at line 1").  

For reference, the 'title' scraped reads as follows: 'AAA prime location - s/s appliances- h/w floors - Avail: July 1st'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the syntax that was able to finally insert data into the database:

```
def process_item (self, item, spider):
    sql = "INSERT INTO items (title) VALUES (%s)"
    data = item['title']

    self.cursor.execute(sql, data)
    self.conn.commit()

    return item
```